cookies are not available in request headers in vercel deployment
I am working on a MERN project. I am trying to implement authentication system. But when running the server in localhost. The cookies are available in request headers but on runnning server on vercel or render. I am not getting the cookies in the header.
Frontend code :
export const getUser = () => {
  return axios.get(`${domain}/api/users/details`, {
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
    },
  });
};

backend(controller)
const loginUser = AsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { userName, password, email } = req.body;

  if (!(userName || email))
    throw new ApiError(400, "Username or email is required");

  const user = await User.findOne({
    $or: [{ userName }, { email }],
  });

  if (!user) throw new ApiError(400, "User not found ");

  const isPasswordValid = await user.isPasswordCorrect(password);

  if (!isPasswordValid) throw new ApiError(401, "Invalid user credentials");

  const { refreshToken, accessToken } = await generateRefreshAndAccessToken(
    user._id
  );

  const loggedInUser = await User.findById(user._id).select(
    "-password -refreshToken"
  );

  const options = {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true,
    sameSite: "None",
    path: "/",
  };

  return res
    .status(200)
    .cookie("access-token", accessToken, options)
    .cookie("refresh-token", refreshToken, options)
    .json(
      new ApiResponse(
        200,
        { user: loggedInUser, accessToken, refreshToken },
        "User logged in successfully"
      )
    );
});

Backend(middlewares):
export const verifyJWT = AsyncHandler(async (req, _, next) => {
  try {
    const token =
      req.cookies?.["access-token"] ||
      req.header("Authorization")?.replace("Bearer ", "");

    if (!token) {
      throw new ApiError(401, "Unauthorized request");
    }

    const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY);

    const user = await User.findById(decodedToken?._id).select(
      "-password -refreshToken"
    );

    if (!user) {
      throw new ApiError(401, "Invalid Access Token");
    }

    req.user = user;
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    throw new ApiError(401, error?.message || "Invalid access token");
  }
});

cors:
const allowedOrigins = [
  "http://localhost:5173",
];
app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: (origin, callback) => {
      if (allowedOrigins.includes(origin) || !origin) {
        callback(null, true);
      } else {
        callback(new Error("Not allowed by CORS"));
      }
    },
  })
);

Routes for getting user detail :
router.get("/details", verifyJWT, getCurrentUser);


Suspiciously close to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78674024/cookie-is-not-getting-send-in-request-headers-after-deployment-to-vercel?noredirect=1#comment138708041_78674024. If you're the same user, please refrain from posting the same question multiple times under different accounts.

no bro .. i tried that .. but that didn't help for me. I am not the same user .

Hi, Is this issue still persisting ?

Hi, Thanks for the interest man. Yes, i still couldn't solve what is the problem. So, I decided to fix this later . And yes, this issue is still there.
